# ¿De dónde proviene la palabra "chiripa"?

Tags: etimología, coloquialismos

La definición que da la RAE de *chiripa* la relaciona con el juego del billar, y coloquialmente la define como *carambola*.

> [**chiripa**](https://dle.rae.es/?id=8rrbhUM)
>   `De or. inc.`
>
> 1. f. En el juego de billar, suerte favorable que se gana por casualidad.
>   2. f. coloq. carambola (‖ casualidad favorable).

El origen podría ser **serendipia** pero es incierto. Por tanto, ¿de dónde viene la palabra *chiripa*?

Comment: in my country, Ecuador, it say for when someone have good luck or do something with luck

Comment: Drewico, lo mismo significa en Perú.

Comment: Chiripa es un pueblo de Costa Rica

Answer (score 4, accepted):

De acuerdo a [esta referencia](http://amarantaserendip.blogspot.com/2012/10/el-termino-enespanol-chiripa-tiene-su.html), el origen etimológico es *serendipia*.

> El término en español "chiripa" tiene su origen etimológico precisamente en la palabra "Serendipia", es decir en la isla de Ceilán, en alusión al cuento persa, donde los problemas se solucionaban por "serendipia", o sea por "chiripa".

en referencia al nombre de la isla de Ceilán.

La web [etimologías de Chile](http://etimologias.dechile.net/?serendipitoso) también relaciona *serendipia* con *chiripa*, y se explica el origen de la primera a través de la historia "Las tres princesas de Serendip" de Horace Walpole, y explica que Serendip es el nombre de Ceilán, la actual Sri Lanka.

[Esta otra referencia](http://365palabras.blogspot.com/2014/06/chiripa.html) también menta *serendipia* como posible origen de *chiripa*, aunque no hace referencia a la isla de Celián (o Serendip). Eso sí, incluye una referencia a un uso de la palabra *chiripa* en una obra del siglo XVIII:

> "...Cogí el cuchillo y lo clavé en la mesa en el mismo sitio que tenía la mano puesta, siendo tal su fortuna, que entre dedo y dedo pasó el cuchillo sin hacer daño. El estudiante que solo por **chiripa** no se vio manco me cogió de los cavezones, y tirándome al suelo, me sacudió tantas patadas, que me dejó medio muerto..."

Comment: No digo que la etimología sea incorrecta, pero ninguno de los tres sitios menciona una fuente verificable (cosa que tampoco ví que hiciera ninguna otra que derive *chiripa* de *serendipia*, y el segundo no relaciona una palabra con la otra, sólo las menciona en el mismo párrafo.

Answer (score 3):

Según la florida explicación dada por [*El folk-lore andaluz: órgano de la sociedad de este nombre*](https://books.google.com/books?id=IXmOgLvJ2-gC&pg=PA16#v=onepage&q&f=false), de 1883:

> *Chispa*, *chiripa* ó *chiripon*, palabras originalmente hebráicas, de la
>   raíz *scharaph=arder, quemar*; naturaleza(*schin*) que realiza
>   (*resch*) á pedir de boca(*phi*) lo que necesita; son voces usadas por
>   el vulgo andaluz para indicar [...] lo poco que á veces hace que nos
>   venga una suerte ó una desgracia [...]

De todos modos, no encontré otra fuente que explique cómo pasó a significar sólo "buena suerte" ni cómo se empezó a asociar con el billar, ni ninguna otra que corrobore lo dicho.

Comment: ¡Gracias! Muy interesante tu respuesta. Seguimos con la duda...

Answer (score 2):

Chirippa proviene del catalán [*xiripa*](http://www.diccionari.cat/lexicx.jsp?GECART=0175844) que el diccionario catalán en línea define como (traducción de Google Translate):

> [1830; de origen incierto, tal vez relacionado con el antiguo *xerip*, moneda de oro, derivada de la raíz árabe šrb ('beber'), con el significado de 'propina que se da para beber' y, posteriormente, 'ganga']
>
> f coloquial 1 Buena suerte
>
> 2 Casualidad favorable.

Answer (score 0):

Viene de la palabra inglesa *cheap* que significa "barato, precio bajo", por algo que se vende o se trabaja.
En República Dominicana, cuando alguien consigue algo para producir o trabajar ganarse el sustento medianamente, suele decir "Estoy haciendo una **chiripa**."

Answer (score 0):

Creo que la voz "Chiripa" no procede ni de Serendipia, ni del catalán, ni del inglés... Con el nombre de "chiripa" encontramos diversos significados, desde "una suerte favorable", a un pueblo del Paraguay llamado "Chiripa" y la referencia a la "Cultura Chiripa" de la zona andina.

Parece que la etimología de la palabra "chiripá" posee dos versiones.

- La que dice provenir del "mapudungun", "chiripa", y que a su vez era préstamo del quechua "chiripak" (de "chiri" frío y "pak" para, "*para el frío*") y designaba inicialmente al chamal masculino mapuche (tipo de tela amplia de lana, muy tupida, que usaban los indígenas araucanos para cubrirse el cuerpo).
- La segunda versión, proviene de las misiones guaraníes, afirmando que en lengua misionero-guaraní, "chiripá" significa cosa de poca monta o valor, casual, de la menor importancia.

Por tanto, se llama "chiripá" a una especie de manta o sobre-vestimenta, colocada en forma de pañal y prendida con alfileres o con faja utilizada originalmente por varios pueblos de América. Esta prenda fue después ampliamente empleada por los gauchos ya que proporcionaba gran comodidad a la hora de cabalgar y protegerse del frío.

[image]

Así, como sobre-vestimenta, la "Chiripá" fue utilizada como prenda por los gauchos. Por debajo de la "Chiripá" los "gauchos" llevaban normalmente un tipo de pantalón blanco con flecos llamados "calzones o calzoncillos". Sin embargo, la calidad de estos calzones junto con el duro y continuo trabajo que desarrollaban a caballo en los campos, daban pronto como resultado el rozamiento y desgaste de esos "calzones-pantalones". De aquí la costumbre de los gauchos de utilizar esta sobre-vestimenta, "Chiripá", como especie de poncho o manta pasado por las entrepiernas y sostenido mediante un cinturón o faja a la cintura.

[image]

En ocasiones, al estar los calzones o pantalones rotos o muy desgastados, la "Chiripá" era utilizada sola, es decir, sin calzoncillos, desprotegiendo por tanto las partes más nobles del gaucho que quedaban expuestas a las inclemencias y a los peligros de los trabajos en el campo. Sin embargo la "Chiripá" también proporcionaba cierta protección en las piernas y genitales de las habituales escaramuzas y peleas entre gauchos con arma blanca. No solo las reyertas eran un peligro, sino hasta finales del S. XIX aproximadamente, era común que los gauchos al defender el ganado tuvieran numerosos encuentros con otros depredadores de la Pampa húmeda, como jaguares o pumas.

Esta prenda llamada "Chiripá" venida por tanto a resguardar y a proteger principalmente las extremidades y genitales de aquellos gauchos que la utilizaban como como parte de su vestimenta y la que daría nombre a la actual " Chiripa".

Así por ejemplo, era normal decir " que por (la) chiripa el jaguar no me mordió... por la "chiripa" el cuchillo de Martín no me lo hinco....por chiripa la astilla que salto no me produjo heridas... convirtiéndose la "Chiripá" al final de este proceso evolutivo,  en esa casualidad favorable con que en la actualidad la nombramos y conocemos.

---

Chiripa

http://etimologias.dechile.net/?chiripa

https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cultura_chiripa

https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pueblo_chirip%C3%A1

https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chirip%C3%A1_(prenda)